# CSS property as SASS mixin value

Tags: html, css, properties, sass, mixins

I try to build some universal margin/padding mixin...

This is my code:

```
[class*="shift"] {
  $sft-o: 10px;
  @mixin shift_stp($val) {
    &[class*="_sml"]{ $val: $sft-o; }
    &[class*="_mid"]{ $val: $sft-o * 2; }
    &[class*="_big"]{ $val: $sft-o * 3; }
  }
  &[class*="_m"]{
    @include shift_stp(margin);
  }
  &[class*="_p"]{
    @include shift_stp(padding);
  }
}
```

Something is not right, so I wonder if it is possible to set some CSS property as a mixin value? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use variables as property names you need to use [**string interpolation**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)  - `#{$var}`.

So this should work:

```
[class*="shift"] {
  $sft-o: 10px;
  @mixin shift_stp($val) {
    &[class*="_sml"]{ #{$val}: $sft-o; }
    &[class*="_mid"]{ #{$val}: $sft-o * 2; }
    &[class*="_big"]{ #{$val}: $sft-o * 3; }
  }
  &[class*="_m"]{
    @include shift_stp(margin);
  }
  &[class*="_p"]{
    @include shift_stp(padding);
  }
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7530159)

**Just a note:** for your attribute selectors ... `*="_m"` will also apply to the ones that have `_mid` in them (see [**here**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7535413)) ... so maybe you should rethink this a little.